# Map Reduce output not correct

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have an input file

```
UserId|TrackId|Shared|Radio|Skip
111115|222|0|1|0
111113|225|1|0|0
111117|223|0|1|1
111115|225|1|0|0
```

I need to add the Shared and Radio columns for all the track IDs
The output should be

```
222,1
223,1
225,2
```

With the below program that I have written, I get

```
222,1
223,1
225,1
225,2.
```

Not sure what the error is

This is my program

```
public class Total {

public static class ListenMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String slt= values.toString();
        String arr[]= slt.split("[|]");
        String trackid= arr[1];
        String shared= arr[2];
        String radio= arr[3];
        int sharenum= Integer.parseInt(shared);
        int radionum= Integer.parseInt(radio);
        int total= sharenum+radionum;
        context.write(new Text(trackid), new IntWritable(total));
    }
}


public static class ListenReduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(IntWritable x: values)
        {
            sum+=x.get();
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));

        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Configuration conf= new Configuration();
    Job job= new Job(conf, "listen");

    job.setJarByClass(Total.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ListenMap.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ListenReduce.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 1:0);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));` outside the loop unless you want to print each value of sum after you increment it.

I'm going to assume the period is a typo in asking the question because your code isn't adding that.

Answer (score 1):

You write out the result in the for loop. Move it outside:

```
public static class ListenReduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(IntWritable x: values)
        {
            sum+=x.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your context object inside for loop, that's why you can see duplicate keys.

Instead It should be written only once for each key.

```
public static class ListenReduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(IntWritable x: values)
        {
            sum+=x.get();
        }
        // Write it here
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
```